# How can I assign a name to a greenlet

Tags: python, gevent

I am looking to assign a custom name/identifier to a gevent greenlet. Gevent already assigns a unique name:

```
def name(self):
    """
    The greenlet name. By default, a unique name is constructed using
    the :attr:`minimal_ident`. You can assign a string to this
    value to change it. It is shown in the `repr` of this object.

    .. versionadded:: 1.3a2
    """
```

However, I am not sure how to change this value to a user inputted name. Is it possible to do so?

I tried to do something like this and ended up with an attribute error:

```
       def begin(self):
          self.thread = gevent.spawn(self.print_message)
          self.thread.minimal_ident = "t1"
          print(self.thread.name) 

AttributeError: attribute 'minimal_ident' of 
'gevent._greenlet.Greenlet' objects is not writable
```

Comment: like `your_greentlet.minimal_ident = 'your fancy name'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gevent.Greenlet.name` is not a common `property`, but a `gevent.util.readproperty` obj, which is [a special non-data descriptor](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/_util.py#L137-L152) works like `@property`, and for a non-data descriptor:

> ... In contrast, non-data descriptors can be overridden by instances.

you could override it simply:

```
>>> gr = gevent.spawn(gevent.sleep, (1,))
>>> gr.name = "a_cool_name"
>>> print(gr)
<Greenlet "a_cool_name" at 0x1082a47b8: sleep((1,))>
```

read more on the gevent source and [the descriptor doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors).

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the class first and then overwrite the method as such;

```
my_obj = Class() #Instantiate the class
my_obj.name = 'this is the string'
```

This will replace the constructed name with your own string.